# Comparing the percentages of dependant categorical with independant categorical value

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have two independant samples: females and males
I wish to investigate if the reasons for discontinuation differ between these two samples (reasons: remission, lack of efficacy, other, adverse events).

Based on my research I would have to do a chi-square test. However, I am also confused, since the chi-square test looks at the difference between expected values and observed values and I would expect a test which assumes that the values (%) in females and males are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expected values" in chi-squared test are those that would occur if percentages in females and males were the same.

So, you research found you an appropriate test.

Keep in mind that you can use chi-squared test provided assumption of high enough expected values is met. Usually expected value of 5 or more is considered "high enough".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Expected values are high (>1000) per cell.